# Order Notation question $\sin(x) = O(1-x)$ as $x\to 1$

Tags: numerical-methods

Is the problem $\sin(x) = O(1-x)$ as $x\to 1$ true or false?

I think that it is false, but I don't know how to prove it. I know that for some ε there exists a constant C so that $|x-a|\leq \epsilon$ implies that $|f(x)-a|\leq  C|g(x)|.$

I don't know what $\epsilon$ or $C$ to choose to show that the above statement is false.

Comment: You need to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ and any $C>0$ there is some $x\in(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon$ where the inequality fails.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x)$ does not go to $0$ as $x$ goes to $1$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @paulgarrett I wonder if $f(n)\in\mathcal O(0)$ is also $\in\mathcal O(\sin(1))$ since _technically_ whatever is bounded from above by $0$ is also bounded from above by $\sin(1)$.

Comment: @an4s, yes, and/but my reading of the question is that it's somewhat opposite of your a-fortiori true fact... Hard to guess what was really intended in the question.

Comment: One could write $\sin(x)=sin(1)+O(1-x)$, this just means that the sine is a little better than continuous in $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly let me note that [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of $g(x) \in O(f(x)), x\to a$ is different from that you wrote:
$$O(f(x)), x\to a = \{ \phi \colon \exists C>0, \exists \varepsilon>0,\forall x \ (0<|x-a|< \varepsilon \Rightarrow |\phi(x)| \leqslant C\cdot |f(x)|)\}$$

So, we need to have $|f(x)|\leqslant  C|g(x)|$, not $|f(x)-a|\leqslant  C|g(x)|$.

Now let's consider inequality
$$|\sin x| \leqslant C|1-x|$$
and let $x \to 1$. Then right side tends to $0$, while left side gives $|\sin 1|>0$. Obtained gives $\sin(x) \notin O(1-x), x \to 1$.